# What the setNull and setInt are doing in this statement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am wondering what the input parameters are referencing in the setNull and setInt methods in the following snippet.  What is the parameter index.  What is the SQL type and how do I determine that from the database columns/data??

public void testQUERY_UPDATEPORTFOLIO() throws Exception{

```
    UnitTestHelper helper = new UnitTestHelper();
    Connection con = helper.getConnection(helper.sourceDBUrl);
    Connection conTarget = helper.getConnection(helper.targetDBUrl);

    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(TRScheduleStatusCalculator.QUERY_UPDATEPORTFOLIO);
    stmt.setNull(1,Types.INTEGER);
    stmt.setInt(2,2290);
    ResultSet sourceVal = stmt.executeQuery();

    stmt = conTarget.prepareStatement(TRScheduleStatusCalculator.QUERY_UPDATEPORTFOLIO);
    stmt.setNull(1,Types.INTEGER);
    stmt.setInt(2,2290);
    ResultSet targetVal = stmt.executeQuery();


    assertTrue(helper.resultSetsEqual(sourceVal,targetVal));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PreparedStatement.setnull(paraIndex, SQLType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) sets the **SQL varchar** type to **Null** for the specified placeholder. 
[stmt.setInt(2,2290);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) sets an int value 2290 at 2nd placeholder .

Comment: select requestid, methodid, workplanid, requiredstart, requiredend from tr_request where fundingportfolioid = ?" + " and requestid <> ?                            _______________________________________________________________________So the first parameter, 1,(1,Types.INTEGER) is for the portfolioid.  And the second parameter, 2, (2, 2290) is for requestid.  Is that correct.  Wherever the ? marks are?

Answer (score 0):

The [setNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) method allows you to send a JDBC/SQL NULL  value to the database as an IN parameter.

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243513/why-does-preparedstatement-setnull-requires-sqltype) to learn more

Answer (score 0):

Setting the value as null: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementSetNullforintvaluecolumn.htm

Its pretty common practice where you clearly set a null for a specific column in the database table

Answer (score 0):

The setNull() call will give a value of null to the first placeholder.

The setInt() call gives a value of 2290 to the second placeholder.

You would need to examine QUERY_UPDATEPORTFOLIO to find the placeholders (question marks) to determine what they correspond to in your database.

Comment: What does "placeholder" mean, the column, row, or both?

Comment: @user1865053 It's the question marks in the query, eg `insert into mytable (col1, col2, col3, col4) values (?, ?, ?, ?)`. It's the column or a value for a condition eg `... where id = ?`